# Is there a performance difference between background-size:cover and background-size:100% auto?

Tags: css, performance, css3, background-image

I know what the difference is between `background-size: cover` and `background-size: 100% auto`.  I'm curious if there is a performance difference between the two and which one would be preferred?

Answer (score 3):

It's always good to go for % because it guarantees fluid content. It's good both for Google and your users to have a good mobile version of your site.

I don't think there would be a difference in the performance or at least not a difference that you can spot. You can test it by putting both of the properties and testing your page speed with a tool for both of them but I am certain that there wouldn't be any difference.

In my opinion, % would be better than cover since it's easier for the browsers to render it and make it fluid for the different resolutions.

Answer (score 3):

There is a performance difference between the two, using `background-size: 100%;` is not supported for Android 4.3 Browser and below. Also, `background-size` percentage values are not properly supported for SVG images on Safari.

Also, iOS Safari has long had very buggy behaviour with `background-size: cover`. All this info is from the excellent [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) website - look under the 'Known issues' tab below the graph.

As a workaround for most of the above you can use the [jQuery Backstretch plugin](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/). It's slower than CSS but the end result might be more satisfactory for you.

If you stick with an abstract pattern, image, or especially a gradient you can probably ignore the random bugs since it is much less likely visitors will notice if the background scales properly.